# POwerShell StreamWriter

Tags: powershell, streamwriter

I have a hash that should contain a lot of related stuff one thing is the 'handle' for a log-file:

```
$myHash = NewObject psobject -Property @{
    # ...
    "LogFile"  = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $($Env:USERPROFILE+"\Documents\Logs\MsgLog.txt")     
    # ...
}
```

This fails with (my translation): The value "C:\Users..." cannot be converted into a "System.IO.StreamWriter"
The path is valid.

What do I have to change?

Thanks in advance
Gooly

Comment: What does the rest of the error say? is it: `"The process cannot access the file '<file name>' because it is being used by another process."`?

Comment: No it says: "C:\Users\...\MsgLog.txt" cannot be converted into a streamWriter.

Comment: There should be more to the message though. If I run `[IO.StreamWriter](get-date)`, I get the message `Cannot convert value "6/16/2014 6:37:24 PM" to type "System.IO.StreamWriter". Error: 
"Invalid cast from 'System.DateTime' to 'System.IO.StreamWriter'."` , but if I run `$a = [IO.StreamWriter]'c:\temp\test.txt';$b = [IO.StreamWriter]'c:\temp\test.txt'`, I get: `Cannot convert value "c:\temp\test.txt" to type "System.IO.StreamWriter". Error: "The 
process cannot access the file 'c:\temp\test.txt' because it is being used by another 
process."`

Comment: This happens to me now too! But only after I am using Keith's version, stopped the debugger and the stream wasn't closed seriously and re-start the script in the debugger. Any hint how the debugger can be told (forced) to dispose/kill/close that stream if debugging is stopped? Right now I need to kill and restart the ISE :(

Comment: You can either call the `Dispose` method or clear the value. (e.g. `$myHash['LogFile'].Dispose()` or `$myHash['LogFile'] = $null`)

Comment: yes - I do that at the normal end of the program - but what if the sript is running in the ISE-Debugger and I stopped the debugger - then the ...Dispose() is not touched - any idea for this pet. problem?

Comment: Just enter it in the ISE's console pane, and run it.

Comment: Another option is to select the line that calls the `Dispose` method and hit `F8`; the ISE will only run the selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$myHash = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    # ...
    LogFile = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\Documents\Logs\MsgLog.txt"
    # ...
```

}

Note: you don't have to quote the key/property names unless you're putting spaces in them.